# Java REST Mailgun

Tags: java, rest, mailgun

I am trying to take advantage of Mailgun's Transactional Email Service via their RESTful API, but I can not make it work. I am able to send emails via SMTP but i prefer to use their API.

Their documentation provides me with the following code:

```
public static ClientResponse SendSimpleMessage() {
       Client client = Client.create();
       client.addFilter(new HTTPBasicAuthFilter("api",
                       "key-*****"));
       WebResource webResource =
               client.resource("https://api.mailgun.net/v2/DOMAIN" +
                               "/messages");
       MultivaluedMapImpl formData = new MultivaluedMapImpl();
       formData.add("from", "Excited User <mailgun@DOMAIN>");
       formData.add("to", "bar@example.com");
       formData.add("to", "bar@example.com");
       formData.add("subject", "Hello");
       formData.add("text", "Testing some Mailgun awesomness!");
       return webResource.type(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED).
               post(ClientResponse.class, formData);
}
```

Obviously I need some kind of REST client to take advantage of this code, but I have not been able to find anything online that works for me. Can someone please explain to me step by step how I make this work. I am using Eclipse, JAVA EE, No Maven

Answer (score 9):

I'm developing a Java mail library to easily send email messages using Mailgun. It may fit your needs.

https://github.com/sargue/mailgun

It allows you to send messages like this:

```
MailBuilder.using(configuration)
    .to("marty@mcfly.com")
    .subject("This is the subject")
    .text("Hello world!")
    .build()
    .send();
```

Even file attachments are easy:

```
MailBuilder.using(configuration)
    .to("marty@mcfly.com")
    .subject("This message has an text attachment")
    .text("Please find attached a file.")
    .multipart()
    .attachment(new File("/path/to/image.jpg"))
    .build()
    .send();
```

There is also support for asynchronous message sending and a HTML mail helper. It is a young project, feedback is very welcome.

Comment: Is it possible to send email using Thymeleaf and your library?

Comment: Thymeleaf seems a template engine. I don't see the relationship, sorry.

Comment: Sargue library didn't work for me. I always get 200 Mailgun Magnificent API (and no email is sent), regardless which API-key is supplied. The maven-jersey-dependencies from the other answer worked - kind of. At least an email was sent.

Comment: I am also having issue with @Sargue library, email are not sent.

Answer (score 1):

You need the following dependencies:

- jersey-core: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.jersey/jersey-core
- jersey-client: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.jersey/jersey-client
- jersey-multipart: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.jersey.contribs/jersey-multipart

You can download the JARs from mvnrepository and add them to your classpath.

Use the following dependencies if you should switch to Maven:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
  <artifactId>jersey-core</artifactId>
  <version>1.19</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
  <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
  <version>1.19</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.sun.jersey.contribs</groupId>
  <artifactId>jersey-multipart</artifactId>
  <version>1.19</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. I don't use Maven and I have no intention of using Maven. Is there a way to implement this without using Maven?

Comment: You can follow the mvnrepository links. Then click the newest version, i.e. "1.19" and then click "Download (JAR)". Finally, add the JAR to the classpath of your project.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try with this post, using basic implementation of MailGun API with Retrofit library: [send mail from android without using smtp and user interaction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30148833/send-mail-from-android-without-using-smtp-and-user-interaction/33897684#33897684)