# send mail from android without using smtp and user interaction

Tags: android, email, mailgun

I want to send email from my android application without any **user interaction**. How can i implement services like ***Mailgun API*** in android?

I found a piece of code in mailgun that works in [java](https://documentation.mailgun.com/quickstart-sending.html#send-via-api). For this implementation i got some [libraries](https://documentation.mailgun.com/libraries.html#java) that doesnot works with android. Anybody have tried to use mailgun in android?

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are asking is outbound sender email which is similar to Mailgun. One such service is Amazon SES which is already incorporated into AWS Mobile [SDK](http://aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdk/). It even has a nice [tutorial](https://developer.amazon.com/public/community/post/TxEUZC89WLEC2Z/Sending-E-mail-with-Amazon-SES-Using-the-AWS-SDK-for-Android) to implement it in Android. Both SES and Mailgun require a verified sender so technically you will be sending emails from your own domain and have nothing to do with user's email.

Answer (score 1):

Send Mail basic implementation, via MailGun API and Retrofit for Android:

```
public class MailGun {

    private static final String TAG = MailGun.class.getSimpleName();
    private static final boolean DEBUG = Config.DEBUG;

    private static final String ENDPOINT = "https://api.mailgun.net/v3/yourdomain.com/";
    public static final String ACCEPT_JSON_HEADER = "Accept: application/json";
    public static final String BASIC = "Basic";

    private SendMailApi sendMailApi;

    public interface SendMailApi {

        @Headers({ACCEPT_JSON_HEADER})
        @FormUrlEncoded
        @POST("/messages")
        void authUser(
                @Header("Authorization") String authorizationHeader,
                @Field("from") String from,
                @Field("to") String to,
                @Field("subject") String subject,
                @Field("text") String text,
                Callback<MailGunResponse> cb
        );
    }

    public void sendMail(String to, String subject, String msg, Callback<MailGunResponse> cb){
        String from = "User Name Maybe <mailgun@yourdomain.com>";
        String clientIdAndSecret = "api" + ":" + "key-AdFEFtggxxxYourApiKey";
        String authorizationHeader = BASIC + " " + Base64.encodeToString(clientIdAndSecret.getBytes(), Base64.NO_WRAP);
        sendMailApi.authUser(authorizationHeader,from, to, subject, msg, cb);
    }

    public MailGun() {
        RestAdapter restAdapter = getAuthAdapter();
        sendMailApi = restAdapter.create(SendMailApi.class);
    }

    private RestAdapter getAuthAdapter(){
        RestAdapter.LogLevel logLevel = RestAdapter.LogLevel.NONE;
        if(DEBUG)logLevel = RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL;
        return new RestAdapter.Builder()
                .setEndpoint(ENDPOINT)
                .setConverter(new GsonConverter(new Gson()))
                .setLogLevel(logLevel)
                .build();
    }

}
```

Complete Github gist: https://gist.github.com/hpsaturn/5fd39a4e7d6ffb156197

Comment: For recent viewers - this uses Retrofit 1.9.  I fiddled with it a bit to convert to Retrofit 2 without success so far.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use javamail. It works fine for me and works on android. [Here is the link to the google code project](https://code.google.com/p/javamail-android/). Although you don't have as much possibilities as in mailgun, for just sending a mail javamail is enough.

Answer (score 0):

```
let key = "dfasewr4353terf34t43fefdf34r"

let EmailBody  = "<html><body><table border='1'><tr><td>Jill</td><td>Smith</td><td>50</td></tr><tr>td>Eve</td><td>Jackson</td><td>94</td></tr><tr><td>John</td><td>Doe</td><td>80</td></tr></table></body></html>"

let parameters = [
  "from":from@fromme.com,
  "to": to@tome.com,
  "subject": "my Email Subject",
  "html": EmailBody,
 "text" = "some text instead of html.Only one is aloowed either text or HTML"  
]


Alamofirerequest(.POST, "https://api.mailgun.net/v3/<MAILGUN-DOMAIN>/messages", parameters:parameters)
  .authenticate(user: "api", password: key)
  .response { (request, response, data, error) in
    println(request)
    println(response)
    println(error)
  }
```